# Adding click autocompletion to conda env activate script

Tags: autocomplete, conda, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using a Python library which uses [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/bashcomplete/) autocompletion. Since I've installed the library in a conda env, I'd like the autocomplete to be associated with it. (Also, since it isn't installed in my primary Python env, adding `eval "$(_FOO_BAR_COMPLETE=source_zsh foo-bar)"` to my `.zshrc` doesn't work.) The documentation for the [library I'm using](https://docs.paperspace.com/gradient/get-started/install-the-cli#enable-autocomplete)  says "if gradient was installed in a virtual environment, the following has to be added to the `activate` script":

```
eval "$(_GRADIENT_COMPLETE=source gradient)"
```

I originally added this to `~/miniconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/venv/scripts/common/activate`, but the autocompletion didn't work. Running

```
source ~/miniconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/venv/scripts/common/activate
```

*does* work, but my shell prepends `via __VENV_DIR__` to the prompt, and the fact that this doesn't happen automatically when I run `conda activate myenv` makes me think this is the wrong way to do it (for one, it isn't disabled when I do `conda deactivate my_env`).

What I'm looking for is the canonical way to add a script to run upon `conda activate x`, then end upon `conda deactivate x`. [This](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#macos-and-linux) seems very close, but it's for adding shell variables with `export` and `unset`. Is there a way to do it with `click`'s autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a small modification of the instructions in [the docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#macos-and-linux) seemed to work for me - I placed the `eval` statement in `env_vars.sh`, and nothing in `deactivate.d`.

My understanding is that `export` is persistent in the shell throughout sessions, and so must be undone with a corresponding `unset`. Whereas `eval` only works for that session, so as soon as the conda env is deactivated it no longer has an effect.

Would be happy to hear more from someone with a deeper understanding of `bash`/`conda` under the hood!